# How to Bring Back Codes Committed in Local Repository After Doing Git Revert

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I am very new to git, and I am in a tricky situation as such:

My current remote repository is in this state:

```
Commit1 -> Commit2 -> Commit3
```

As I was working with another developer, we both started out with `Commit1`. He was working on the branch with `Commit2` and `Commit3`.

However, code changes in `Commit2` and `Commit3` are not desired, and in the meantime, I have my own version of code changes which I started with `Commit1`, and I want to merge the changes to `Commit1` while reverting `Commit2` and `Commit3`.

So I started with committing my codes to the local repository (with `git add --all` and `git commit -m "my commit"`).

Thereafter, I seem to have made a mistake... I did `git revert --no-commit [Commit1 id]..HEAD` and all my codes are reverted back to `Commit1`.

However, I looked at `git show`, my codes are still committed somewhere in the local repository.

May I know how to get back my committed codes in the local repository? And thereafter, push it back to merge with `Commit1` in the remote repository?

Answer (score 1):

You have basically done a HEAD reset and all your changes made in the Repository were  reverted back
Use this to see where exactly did you pushed it
***git reflog***
And then revert the changes using

git reset 'HEAD@{1}'

If it was your first ever reset

!!!!! Checkout a new branch before you do this since i am also new to git and still a novice who ran into the same problem !!!!!!!

Comment: Thanks! So, in the end, I did a `git checkout [my commit id]` to bring my committed codes back, and did a `git push -f` to merge the local commit to overwrite `Commit2&3` :D